# Advance search of text files

Tags: vb.net, filestream

Does anyone know how to read blocks of text within a file? Here's what I'm looking for...

The file will look similar to the following:

...

```
STANDARD 1.abc def 1.000 \
        STAMP="0A7B 1258 AC82 470F 682B D06A 4FD5 \
        A108 5A1B 474B A5D5 F241 B9C8 04A9 6455 0B0C E3B4 AFF6 39E5 \
        A5AE F951 FF30 0870 288C F900 6C53 12B6 EBB3 3A3D 57A2" \

ADVANCED 1.abc ghi 1.000 \
        STAMP="076F 1C48 BBC2 0779 EB13 2063 E61D 1DB4 \
        DE9A 6BFF 0E5E 06BE 477D EECF 83D6 069E ADAA 5BDC 8947 9A9B \
        30F7 4042 C4EA BFC6 4ECF 993A EEE4 9180 13FE C8C7"
```

...

This pattern repeats throughout the file which also have a "STAMP2=" section after the "STAMP" section. Also, ADVANCED depends on STANDARD, meaning both must exist. I need to find the Standard section (which is a easy process), but then find the assigned ADVANCED section and assign the STAMP value (everything between the quotes) to a string variable.

Is there an easy way of accomplishing this task, and if so please share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help you. You need nested checks to find out which section is now being read.

NOTE: This is not a complete code, it is just a starter to have you an idea.

```
Const STANDARD As String = "STANDARD"
Const ADVANCE As String = "ADVANCE"
Dim sectionIdentifier As String

Dim standardSection As New StringBuilder
Dim advanceSection As New StringBuilder

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ReadFile("YourFilePathHere")
End Sub

Sub ReadFile(ByVal path As String)
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(path)
    Dim line As String = String.Empty
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        If (line.StartsWith(STANDARD)) Then
            sectionIdentifier = line.Replace(STANDARD, "").Trim
            ReadStandardSection(reader)
        End If
    End While
    reader.Close()
End Sub

Sub ReadStandardSection(ByRef reader As StreamReader)
    Dim line As String = String.Empty
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        If (line.TrimStart().StartsWith("ADVANCE")) Then
            Dim sectionidentiferAdv As String = line.Replace(ADVANCE, "").Trim
            If (sectionIdentifier <> sectionidentiferAdv) Then
                ' display alert advance section for identifier not found
                ' possibly return from here, since file structure is not expected.
            End If
            Debug.Print(standardSection.ToString())
            Debug.Print("standard end")
            standardSection.Clear()
            '' standard data can be use and clear
            ReadAdvanceSection(reader)
        Else
            standardSection.AppendLine(line)
        End If
    End While
End Sub

Sub ReadAdvanceSection(ByRef reader As StreamReader)
    Dim line As String = String.Empty
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        If (line.StartsWith(STANDARD)) Then
            Debug.Print(advanceSection.ToString())
            Debug.Print("advance end")
            advanceSection.Clear()
            '' advance section data can be use and clear
            Return
        End If
        advanceSection.AppendLine(line)
    End While
    If (reader.EndOfStream) Then
        Debug.Print(advanceSection.ToString())
        Debug.Print("advance end")
    End If
End Sub
```

Console log:

```
        STAMP="0A7B 1258 AC82 470F 682B D06A 4FD5 \
        A108 5A1B 474B A5D5 F241 B9C8 04A9 6455 0B0C E3B4 AFF6 39E5 \
        A5AE F951 FF30 0870 288C F900 6C53 12B6 EBB3 3A3D 57A2" \
        STAMP2="0A7B 1258 AC82 470F 682B D06A 4FD5 \
        A108 5A1B 474B A5D5 F241 B9C8 04A9 6455 0B0C E3B4 AFF6 39E5 \
        A5AE F951 FF30 0870 288C F900 6C53 12B6 EBB3 3A3D 57A2" \


standard end
        STAMP="076F 1C48 BBC2 0779 EB13 2063 E61D 1DB4 \
        STAMP="076F 1C48 BBC2 0779 EB13 2063 E61D 1DB4 \
        DE9A 6BFF 0E5E 06BE 477D EECF 83D6 069E ADAA 5BDC 8947 9A9B \
        30F7 4042 C4EA BFC6 4ECF 993A EEE4 9180 13FE C8C7"
        STAMP2="076F 1C48 BBC2 0779 EB13 2063 E61D 1DB4 \
        STAMP2="076F 1C48 BBC2 0779 EB13 2063 E61D 1DB4 \
        DE9A 6BFF 0E5E 06BE 477D EECF 83D6 069E ADAA 5BDC 8947 9A9B \
        30F7 4042 C4EA BFC6 4ECF 993A EEE4 9180 13FE C8C7"


advance end
        STAMP="0B7B 1258 AC82 470F 682B D06A 4FD5 \
        A108 5A1B 474B A5D5 F241 B9C8 04A9 6455 0B0C E3B4 AFF6 39E5 \
        A5AE F951 FF30 0870 288C F900 6C53 12B6 EBB3 3A3D 57A2" \
        STAMP2="0B7B 1258 AC82 470F 682B D06A 4FD5 \
        A108 5A1B 474B A5D5 F241 B9C8 04A9 6455 0B0C E3B4 AFF6 39E5 \
        A5AE F951 FF30 0870 288C F900 6C53 12B6 EBB3 3A3D 57A2" \


standard end
        STAMP="A76F 1C48 BBC2 0779 EB13 2063 E61D 1DB4 \
        STAMP="A76F 1C48 BBC2 0779 EB13 2063 E61D 1DB4 \
        DE9A 6BFF 0E5E 06BE 477D EECF 83D6 069E ADAA 5BDC 8947 9A9B \
        30F7 4042 C4EA BFC6 4ECF 993A EEE4 9180 13FE C8C7"
        STAMP2="076F 1C48 BBC2 0779 EB13 2063 E61D 1DB4 \
        STAMP2="076F 1C48 BBC2 0779 EB13 2063 E61D 1DB4 \
        DE9A 6BFF 0E5E 06BE 477D EECF 83D6 069E ADAA 5BDC 8947 9A9B \
        30F7 4042 C4EA BFC6 4ECF 993A EEE4 9180 13FE C8C7"

advance end
```